# Protection of azure databases for accidental resource group deletion

Tags: azure, devops

We are rolling out a new product in azure and need to be absolutely sure the data in our azure databases does not get lost. i understand the backup features of azure databases, replication and long term storage which all meets our needs fine.

However, if a resource group is accidentally deleted i would assume all databases, backups ect are deleted.

Is there any backup mechanism we can use and store the backup in storage external to the resource group?

I am familiar export bacpac capability but am not sure this is the best approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent the resource from being deleted accidentally by applying a Lock. To do so, go to your Azure SQL management blade, look under the Settings heading, and choose "Lock". On the Lock management blade, create a new Delete lock. See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-lock-resources).

Comment: Thanks Rob, I saw that but this brings up a larger question for me. Azure has all sorts of fault tolerance built into it. Geo redundant database, replication ect. But, if my whole set of data is lost forever if a resource group  is deleted that is scary. So I guess I will add to my question is there any way to get back my databases if the resource group they are in is deleted?

Comment: There is no way to recover a deleted resource in a resource group if the resource group is deleted. Your only options are to restore from a backup.